# What would cause UITableView to get clear background?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

Here's one for ya. I have several table views in my application that have been working fine since 4.0 and up.... so far. One table view in my app decided to inherit a clear background color for some reason.

XCode 4.3 (5.1 & 6.0) - fine

XCode 4.4 (5.1) - clear background

Xcode 4.4 (6.0) - fine

I only add the fact that 6.0 works because it worked in prior versions of 5.1 in Lion. Upgraded to `Mountain Lion GM` and Xcode 4.4. Nuttin. I've attached screenshots showing my splash screen from when I start the app or logout peeking through what should be a pushed view from my nav controller. I'm not setting the background color of any table view in my app. None of the other views are affected and are being pushed the same way.

Maybe it is just something goofy in ML and Xcode 4.4, but I thought I would check and see if it is possible there is something I missed. I'll likely be filing a radar for this as well. Seems kinda fishy to me.

[image]

Comment: It's unlikely to be a compiler error so this is most probably unrelated to your Xcode version, rather seems a bug in UIKit in iOS 5.

Comment: Seems that may be the case. Was hoping for something I might have missed, but I doubt it. To bugreport.apple.com

Comment: Have you tried actually setting the background color? I know that shouldnt be necessary, but just set it to red or something to see if that actually does anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got my background to use the default background. In interface builder, I had the tableview style as grouped, and it showed grouped. When I selected it and chose grouped again, the background reset to the normal default and I haven't had any issues with it since.

I'm going to chalk this one up to opening projects up between the production Xcode and beta versions. I think something just got out of sync in the xib file. Nothing fancy needed to fix this one. Thank you to everyone that answered.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your CellForRowAtInedx method

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

And in ViewDidLoad

```
UITableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

This Worked for me.

Best Luck n Happy Coding !!

Comment: I don't want the background clear... I just want the default background to show up like it was before.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the background color in iOS 5 does cause some problems. try setting your UITableView background property programmatically instead of from IB and it should work fine.

```
UITableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor someCOlor]; OR
UITableView.backgroundView = // Perhaps some UIImageView with image property set.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this code in viewDidLoad:-

```
   yourTblView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
   yourTblView.backgroundView  = nil;
```

This will make your background clear.

Comment: I don't want the background clear... I just want the default background to show up like it was before.